# Error: Could not understand expression: .OfType().GroupBy(a => a.Id) RavenDb

Tags: c#, ravendb

I'm currently trying to get the right VAT percentage from the database for an invoice. My code looks like this:

```
var lines = store.Query<DebetInvoiceItemAll.Mapping, DebetInvoiceItemAll>()
               .Where(a => a.InvoiceId.Equals(invoice.Id, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
               .As<DebetInvoiceDistributedPurchaseItem>()
               .All().ToList();
value = info.Amount;
decimal totalInvoicePrice = invoice.TotalDecimal ?? 0m;
decimal percentagePaid = value / totalInvoicePrice;
var rates = store.Query<VATPercentageAll.Mapping, VATPercentageAll>()
                .As<VATPercentage>()
                .GroupBy(a => a.Id)
                .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a
                .ToDictionary(b => b.CountryId, b => b.Percentage, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

when I try to run the code it crashes at the final line. The error says:

> Could not understand expression: .OfType().GroupBy(a => a.Id).

However the problem is not in myGroupBy but at the ToDictionary. Does anyone know why it throws this exception?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is that statement in your code?

Comment: What statement? Sorry i'm pretty new here.

Comment: `OfType`... There is an error with it, but your source code doesn't show a call.

Comment: ToDictornary() throws the expection because that's the point where to query gets evaluated.

Comment: I think the ofType is called by As<VATPercentage>().
But when I remove the ToDictionary the code works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to run a `GroupBy` on a RavenDB query, but that isn't supported.
If you want to do group bys, you need to use a map/reduce index.